# Autodesk forge translations produces different results

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge

I'm finding that the register endpoint (POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/register) is returning different results for the same file. That is, it's non-deterministic.

Here's the expected result after uploading and registering my scissors assembly: https://gist.github.com/sabrehagen/660dad87c9c5948ec042c62f347a9f1d

Here's a different unexpected result after uploading and registering my scissors assembly: https://gist.github.com/sabrehagen/54aaabaf4651ed8da1911f2494308f05

Here are the files for the [scissors assembly](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/files/scissors.zip).

Why am I receiving different results when rendering the exact same file?

Comment: Hi @sabrehagen, may I know you ran the same workflow of code to register(translate)  the file? This an assembly, So I assumed you have set the reference of the parts, and also uploaded the parts.The expected result contains the information of parts, while the unexpected  does not.

Comment: In addition, I do not suggest with v1/register because with endpoint of v2 https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/ you can upload an zip of assembly and parts, and only set the root file = top assembly, Forge will identify the  hierarchy automatically.  It is quite easy than set reference of v1.

Comment: Thank you @XiaodongLiang. Yes, these two results were created using the same workflow. No, assembly references were not set, only the assembly file was uploaded and registered. I do not have access to a zip of the files, so I use the failed assembly registration to identify supporting files, then upload and set references. The unexpected result is where the missing files are not listed, and this is the information I need.

Comment: I understood the question now. So with same assembly (only this root file) and same code workflow of Forge, sometimes you got a result that contains the information of the referenced (sub-assemblies /parts) of the root file, while sometimes, no information of referenced files. I tested with v1 or v2, both of them do not return referenced information. I will consult with our engineer team on the behaviors. Could you also check if there is any special steps that could reproduce the issue? it would be helpful with a few lines on how to configured the parameters for that HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough investigation. I can send you the http transactions, but they are too long for stackoverflow. Do you have an email I can send them to?

Comment: @sabrehangen, my email address: xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com

Comment: @sabrehangen, I have not got a comment from our engineer team. I did not seem to receive your email.  Will you have a chance to mail me the demo codes you are using?Thanks.